# Export Restriction of wrapper for existing crypto library

Tags: legal

I am creating a packaged C++ library for creating http/https clients/servers. As part of that, I am planning on using either the botan (http://botan.randombit.net/) or openssl tls wrappers.  My library will be open-source (hosted on github) and also have downloadable binaries available so the user can start using it immediately without having to build the library.

In this situation, are there notifications/regulations that I have to fulfill prior to posting my source code and binaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legal matters are inherently complex because they depend on the jurisdiction, and with 193 countries or so (193 UN members, plus a few odd cases like Vatican, not counting federal countries which induce extra splits) there are a lot of cases to cover. When proposing some opensource software for download, you are actually giving it away to the *whole world* so you are both providing it to other people and exporting it, so regardless of where in the world you live, and where the servers are, chances are that *many* regulations apply.

See [this site](http://www.cryptolaw.org/) for a lot of pointers and explanations.

My own prejudice suggests to me that since you don't specify which country you live in, then you are probably American, and you implicitly refer to US laws and regulations. Since 2011, there is a [relaxed clause](http://www.cryptolaw.org/cls2.htm#us_exp_1101) for opensource software, which might apply to your case. Or not. If it really worries you, ask a lawyer (which I am not).